# How would I determine the charge density of an active lava flow?

Tags: electrons, electric-current, charge, geophysics

It is my understanding that in molten silicates, such as a basaltic lava flow, electrons are decoupled from solid state structures. If this is the case, as lava is flowing through a tube, how would I estimate the charge density and current of the flow for a given composition...say at 10m/s?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps through the use of some sort of semiconductor material. I am watching a documentary right now and it is talking about the sun being misunderstood as just a ball of burning gas . On the contrary it is an electrically charged sphere of what they believe is a liquid material. Could be very possible that lava could have a similar electrical charge. It would also would explain lightening when some volcanoes explode or even how gravity works . Perhaps there is an electromagnetic condition that comes into play deep under the Earth's surface.

Comment: On Physics Stack Exchange, the ‘post answer button’ is meant to be used to post a complete answer, as opposed to speculation. The reason we do this is that a person Googling a similar question can immediately see a response to it if it has been asked before. This can’t be always done if some speculation or partial answers clutter the page. It would be best if you deleted this answer before it incurs a negative score, as some users will downvote answers which go against policy even if they are from new users. Best of luck in future interactions with the site.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/368558)